# Splitting value in React MUI textfield into an array of strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently using React with Material UI to create a webpage for a project that allows editors to edit written scripts. I apologise in advance if this is a basic question, as I'm fairly new to React.

The page consist of one text field as follows: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v23Oi.png

I first assemble the segments (string[]) from a query into the textfield as follows:

```
const scriptCompiledSegments = (() => {
    let script = "";
    _.forEach(segments, segment => {
      script += segment;
    });
    return script;
  })();
```

I then display the compiled script as follows:

```
 <TextField
            InputProps={{
              classes: {
                input: classes.input,
              },
            }}
            id="script-field"
            margin="normal"
            multiline
            rows={35}
            variant="outlined"
            defaultValue={scriptCompiledSegments}
            onChange={(event) => {
              setEditedScripts({ updatedSegments: (event.target.value) })
            }}
          />
```

Currently, event.target.value returns the script in a single string. I need to use a delimiter to split the script in the textfield back into its original array of segments. I was planning to split based on newline, but was given feedback that I should not be using that to split, but an "invisible" delimiter instead as segments might not have newlines between them.

The project was given restriction as follows:

1. I can only use one textfield instead of seperate textfields for each segment.
2. I cannot split via new line, as I should assume that the assembled script may not have newline between segments.
3. Editors should not be able to edit the delimiter in the textfield, or see it for that matter.

I have tried using "‌&zwnj" between different segment in scriptCompiledSegments but it will render in the textfield as editors edit the scripts. Could anyone suggest a solution? I would be open to using a different library for a specialised text field if its necessary.

EDIT:

I'm currently investigating wrapping the segments in a span. It does seem like it's keeping the segment seperated while presenting them in a seamless script. If anyone could share their advice on how to make the span editable, that would be great too.

Comment: Why not using `\n`? If you try to break line in regular `textarea` and get its `value`, you'll see the `\n` inside.

Comment: Hi, I think that could have worked actually but I have already scrapped the textfield to do a span for each segment. Thanks for the recommendation still.